# Hover over one span and change background color of that span plus another one by adding and removing a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<span id="english">Yes</span>
<span id="spanish">Sí</span>
```

How can I hover over any of these and change background color to yellow on both. I can't use onmouseout() because the background color changes dynamically due to other scripts.
I'm aware that I can add a class skipping the use of jQuery -although it's a valid choice if all else fails- by using something like:

```
document.getElementById(id).className += " yellow";
```

and the css would be:

```
.yellow {
background-color: yellow
}
```

My previous solution that included onmouseout() was:

```
function chbg(color, id1, id2) {
document.getElementById(id1).style.backgroundColor = color;
document.getElementById(id2).style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<span id="english" onmouseover="chbg('yellow', 'english', 'spanish')"      onmouseout="chbg('white','english', 'spanish')">Yes</span>
<span id="spanish" onmouseover="chbg('yellow', 'english', 'spanish')" onmouseout="chbg('white','english', 'spanish')">Sí</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JQuery` `hover` function instead.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("span").hover(
    function(){
        $('span').css('background', 'yellow');
    }, 
    function(){
        $('span').css('background', 'white');
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo #1 (With Class)](http://jsfiddle.net/5K6LC/3/)**

**[JSFiddle Demo #2 (Without Class)](http://jsfiddle.net/5K6LC/4/)**

**UPDATE #1**

Use `toggleClass()` function instead.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("span").hover(function(){
        $('span').toggleClass('highlight');
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5K6LC/5/)**

**UPDATE #2**

Assign a `class` to all the `span` that needs to be highlighted. For example: `class="highlight"`. Using `toggleClass()` to toggle a `class`  from `CSS` will add another class now. This way only `span` with `.highlight` change color.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5K6LC/7/)**

Comment: If I hover over Sí, only Sí gets highlighted. Also worths noting that they'll be a bunch of other stuff between these two spans so I don't think + would work.

Comment: Editing answer... Please wait :)

Comment: Yes. If there's no other way then jQuery would have to do it.

Comment: Looks great but it can't return to background-color white. That will change dynamically and depends on other scripts.

Comment: Why can't you change back to white background like in the fiddle?

Comment: Updated it once again :)

Comment: Because the site runs media audio overlay that dynamically highlights the phrase being read (an audio-text sync) so if I set background color to white then it brokes that part of the script that highlights the phrase being read. That's why I originally suggested an addclass solution.

Comment: So even the new update with `toggleClass()` won't work?

Comment: almost there. The problem now is that your solution covers all spans. How can I make it specific to two IDs. English/Spanish a pair, then imagine several hundred different pairs, as English87/Spanish87.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5K6LC/7/ like this :) having 2 classes now... Updating answer to make it better!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with only CSS, by adjusting your HTML a bit:

```
<span id="bghover">
    <span>Yes</span>
    <span>Sí</span>
</span>
```

And for the CSS:

```
#bghover span
{
    background-color: white;
}
#bghover:hover span
{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

So you wrap the two spans into a span or div with id `bghover`, which is only used as a trigger for CSS `:hover`. If there's no hover, all spans within `#bghover` are white, if there is a hover (similar to onmouseover), all spans within `#bghover` are white.

Comment: I can't wrap the two spans into a span. And I can't specify a white background color. It changes.

Comment: Do you mean: you can't because you get errors or something, or you can't because it won't fit in the system you're building?

Comment: I have a setting where I have multiple phrases. Each one has a corresponding translation. And each block is in a different paragraph, in different sections of the site. If I apply your solution all phrases get highlighted.

Comment: Ah, so the spans are actually in two completely different places?

Comment: Yes. It's a sort of translation app. So if you see a "yes" and hover over there you'll see the corresponding word in the other language because the background color would change. And this works both ways. That's why I believe css won't be enough.

Comment: That makes sense. Looks like indeed CSS won't work for this. Then I would recommend going for adding classes like you said in the original post. That is very doable without jQuery.